# How to verify this is an orthogonal basis? How to transform it into an orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

> Let
>   $$B = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 3\\ -3\\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 2\\ -1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 4\end{bmatrix}\right\},\qquad v =\begin{bmatrix} 5\\ -3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
>   a) Verify that $B$ is an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>   b) Transform $B$ into an orthonormal basis.
>   c) Write $v$ as linear combination of $B$.

I am really lost in class. I don't even know where to start. Please show steps and answers for the exercise problem so that I can learn. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you write down the definitions of the things you don't understand?

Comment: I am assuming the same thing as user66345, and I have made an edit to that effect.

Comment: @JoMo: Note that you need to end a line with two spaces in order for the line break to appear.

Comment: My family is a rather huge set so I think they must be linear dependent...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ha ha! Yes, most likely. It is good to know you can depend on your relatives.

Comment: My hints were far from optimal anyway. I suffer from matrix obsession. See Mhenni Benghorbal's answer for good hints.

Comment: @julien: Everyone is obsessed with something.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

a) Take the dot product of the vectors and it should be zero for any two different vectors.

b) Divide each vector by its length.

c) $v = \alpha b_1 + \beta b_2 + \gamma b_3 $

To determine the $\alpha,\beta$, and $\gamma$, take the dot product of $v$ with $b_1,b_2$, and $b_3$ and note that $b_i.||b_i||=1,\, \forall i=1..3$. Note that, $\alpha,\beta$, and $\gamma$ are known as the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: For a) But that just shows that they are orthogonal set. But how do we show that B is an orthogonal basis of R^3?